# If-Then-Else Conditionals Regular Expressions Query in Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I'm trying to extract the *ContactLastName*, by filtering out the *ContactOwnerId*.

First of all, I am extracting the *"ContactOwnerId"* from Sampler No. 1 through Regular Expression Extractor which is successful.

My RegEx Query is:
`"OWNERID":(\d+),`

Now, I want the *"LastName"* by filtering out the *"ContactOwnerId"* from Sampler No. 2 through the Regular Expression Extractor.

My RegEx Query is:
`(?(?"OWNERID":(\d+),==\${GetContactOwnerId})(?"LASTNAME":"(.*?)"))`

**Note:** The both *"LastName"* & *"ContactOwnerId"* can be extracted from Sampler No. 1 & 2, but I'm extracting the *"ContactOwnerId"* first from the Sampler No. 1 and then trying to extract the *"LastName"* from the Sampler No. 2 by comparing extracted *"ContactOwnerId"* with the current *"ContactOwnerId"*.

The 2nd Regular Expression Extractor fails to extract, please verify and suggest the proper query.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following way, the issue got resolved:

As mentioned I was extracting the "ContactOwnerId" from the Sampler No. 1 through the Regular Expression Extractor.

My RegExp Query was: `"OWNERID":(\d+),`

In the 2nd Sampler, I was trying to extract the LastName again through the Regular Expression Extractor.

My RegExp Query was: `(?(?"OWNERID":(\d+),==\${GetContactOwnerId})(?"LASTNAME":"(.*?)"))`

I felt it's complicated using the If-Then-Else pattern in RegExp Query, hence used the NOT operator in my RegExp Query and it worked successfully.

First, I tried with static data which worked error-less;

RegExp Query: `"OWNERID":((?!724812)\d+),.*?"LASTNAME":"(.*?)"`

I just appended the **?!** in my RegExp which implies NOT operator.

Then, I tried extracting using the dynamic variable;

RegExp Query: `"OWNERID":((?!${__V(${GetOwnerId})})\d+),.*?"LASTNAME":"(.*?)"`

Here, I used the **V Function** which returns the value of evaluating a variable name.